# AngularJS DateRange - how to include the end date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-range

I'm using a data range filter on an angular dataset, however it is not 'including' the end date. I have to select +1 day from the date picker for it to work properly. The start date is working fine.

This code is example only and not production...

JAVASCRIPT

```
// parse a date in dd-mm-yyyy format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('-');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]); 
}

nameSpace.filter("rangeFilter", function() {
  return function(items, from, to) {
        var df = parseDate(from);
        var dt = parseDate(to);
        var arrayToReturn = [];        
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            var tf = new Date(items[i].date1 * 1000);
            if (tf >= df && tf < dt)  {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
 };
});
```

HTML

```
From:<input  ng-model="datef"  type="text" placeholder="" />
To:<input  ng-model="datet"  type="text" placeholder="" />

<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | rangeFilter:datef:datet">
    <td>{{order.date1 * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
```

SCOPE / CONTROLLER

```
nameSpace.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.datef = "27-05-2010"
  $scope.datet = "29-07-2015";
  $scope.orders = [
  {
    "date1": 1306281600
  },
  {
    "date1": 1196467200
  },
  {
    "date1": 1406505600
  },
  {
    "date1": 1406592000
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not passing the "to" parameter correctly.
As the official Documentation says(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), the returning function of each filter accept 3 params like this:
    return function(array, expression, comparator){...}
To pass both "from" and "to" parameters, you should pass them to the function using an object:

HTML

```
From:<input  ng-model="datef"  type="text" placeholder="" />
To:<input  ng-model="datet"  type="text" placeholder="" />

<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | rangeFilterr:{from: datef, to: datet}">
<td>{{order.date1 * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// parse a date in dd-mm-yyyy format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('-');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]); 
}

nameSpace.filter("rangeFilter", function() {
  return function(items, obj) {
        var df = parseDate(obj.from);
        var dt = parseDate(obj.to);
        var arrayToReturn = [];        
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            var tf = new Date(items[i].date1 * 1000);
            if (tf >= df && tf < dt)  {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
 };
});
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried this with the slight adjustment of  <code>rangeFilterr:{from: datef, end: date}</code> and <code>var dt = parseDate(obj.end);</code> and still no joy.  It does filter, but for example to include 29-07-2014 I'd have to sent my end date to 30-07-2014

Comment: Sorry, I mispelled the variable name, try with <code>rangeFilterr:{from: datef, to: datet}</code>, and <code>var dt = parseDate(obj.to);</code>