# AngularJS existing ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see my question here.....

[AngularJS DateRange - how to include the end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770995/angularjs-daterange-how-to-include-the-end-date/35771267?noredirect=1#comment59215474_35771267)

How would I go about adding this functionality into an existing ng-repeat area setup?  The current filtering is only done via a single text box - search.  The date from and date to fields need to be added to the filter.

Really appreciate the help.

NG-REPEAT

```
<div class="itemlist" data-token="{{data.token}}" ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" data-name="{{data.customerName}}" ng-click="eventHandler(data, $event)">
```

SEARCH BOX

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
```

I've tried altering NG-REPEAT to the following but it doesn't work, the model datef/datet input boxes aren't shown on this example...but they do exist.

```
<div class="itemlist" data-token="{{data.token}}" ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | myfilter:{from: datef, end: datet} | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" data-name="{{data.customerName}}" ng-click="eventHandler(data, $event)">
```

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that you want to a) filter by a date range (starDate thru endDate) & b) you want to filter that 'dated' data set based on a key/value search?

Comment: That's exactly it! The JSON list currently contains a dated field, so that field needs to sit inside the specified date range. Then, search key/value on other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is how you're adding your filters to the `ng-repeat`.  This syntax is a bit unfamiliar to me but I got it working in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/grpypp?editors=1010)

The core of this is understanding the expression you're trying to execute on.  I asked a comment:

> Am I correct in my understanding that you want to a) filter by a date range (starDate thru endDate) & b) you want to filter that 'dated' data set based on a key/value search

To which you replied:

> That's exactly it...

That being said, the best way to understand the filters and the expression is to think of them as being a chain of logic bits.  So for this:

```
listData | dateRange:startDate:endDate | filter:filterCriteria
```

is doing this:

1. gets the source `listData`
2. passes the resulting array to the `dateRange` filter you're defining
3. passes the resulting array to the built-in angular `filter` filter (they poorly named that btw)

The last bit of this is taking the result of that logic chain and passing it to the ng-repeat process.  So in this case:

```
ng-repeat="obj in filtered = listData | range:startDate:endDate | filter:filterBy"
```

#### note

In my example, I didn't add the *pagination* or the `orderBy` filter.  But your initial filtered value that's contained inside parenthesis...

```
(list | filter:search | myfilter:{from: datef, end: datet} | orderBy : predicate :reverse)
```

... can probably be removed from the parenthesis because you're just passing the return value of each filter on down the chain of filters.

Comment: Thanks, you were absolutely right that it was down to the order of applying the filters.  I think my problem is that I misunderstood the built-in 'filter' property and was trying to apply my filter on top of that.